# how to pass style in div using typescript in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

this is my code i just want to make a custom component in react with typescript like if i want to pass height, width, border Radius and style as extra parameter like if i want more css property then pass style={{display:flex}} but i can't add this with typescript i successfully write in js it works but not familiar with typescript

my interface

```
interface BoxProps {
    heights: React.CSSProperties;
    styles?: React.CSSProperties;
    className?: String;
    borderRadius?: React.CSSProperties
    children?: React.ReactElement<any>
}

const Box = ({ id, heights, styles, className, children }: BoxProps) => {
    const Nstyle = { ...styles,height: { heights } }
    return (
        <div
            {...id}
            style={Nstyle}
            className={CN} >
            {children}
        </div >
    );
}
```

please help style shows this error with typescript
`The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type`'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLDivElement>'`

Comment: try `Nstyle as any`

Comment: What's the definition of the `id` prop?  It's missing from `BoxProps`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prop `heights` needs to be `string | number`.  The `className` prop used a capital `S` for `String` instead of `string`.  `className={CN}` should be `className={className}` because the variable `CN` does not exist.

```
interface BoxProps {
  heights: string | number;
  styles?: React.CSSProperties;
  className?: string;
  borderRadius?: React.CSSProperties
  children?: React.ReactElement<any>
}

const Box = ({ heights, styles, className, children }: BoxProps) => {
  const Nstyle: React.CSSProperties = { ...styles, height: heights }
  return (
      <div
        style={Nstyle}
        className={className}
      >
          {children}
      </div >
  );
}
```